# How do I get data from selected points in an offline plotly python jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Example code:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

import plotly.graph_objs as go

import numpy as np

N = 30
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

# Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
iplot(data, filename='basic-scatter')
```

[[image]]

How do I get a copy of the x,y data, or the indices from the selection?

Comment: Events are currently supported only for javascript, is a javascript solution fine? You need to embed that inside the jupyter notebook

Comment: how do I embed the javascrpt?  I know I can IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(...) once I am running within javascript.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to use javascript in Jupyter notebooks you have two options.

Using the `display(HTML())` method for rendering html inside jupyter notebook, this method is demonstrated in the below sample code!

Another method is to use IPython Magic, read more [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html), the code will go something like this.

> %%html 
>   %html [--isolated] Render the cell as a block of HTML
>
> optional arguments:
>   --isolated    Annotate the cell as ‘isolated’. Isolated cells are rendered inside their own  tag

```
%%html
<span> naren</span>
```

You can also use this above method to render the HTML.

Please check the below code, where I have taken the code for `select event` from the [plotly javascript events docs](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#select-event) and made it work for jupyter!

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML


N = 30
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

# Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
plot = plot(data, filename='basic-scatter', include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
divId=plot.split("id=\"",1)[1].split('"',1)[0]
plot = plot.replace("Plotly.newPlot", "var graph = Plotly.newPlot")
plot = plot.replace("</script>", """
var graph = document.getElementById('"""+divId+"""');
var color1 = '#7b3294';
var color1Light = '#c2a5cf';
var colorX = '#ffa7b5';
var colorY = '#fdae61';
;graph.on('plotly_selected', function(eventData) {
  var x = [];
  var y = [];

  var colors = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) colors.push(color1Light);

  eventData.points.forEach(function(pt) {
    x.push(pt.x);
    y.push(pt.y);
    colors[pt.pointNumber] = color1;
  });


  Plotly.restyle(graph, 'marker.color', [colors], [0]);
});
""")
display(HTML(plot))
```

Comment: @Nizam You're Welcome! Thank you :)

Comment: I copy-pasted above code to an empty notebook and it is not working (nothing is displayed)